# Jquery ui shake effect keeps trigering

Tags: jquery-ui

Strange issue.

Using jquery ui effect like this:

```
<a href="in" style="position:absolute;" ><img src="images/img.png" id="perlabot"  ></a>
$('#perlabot').on('mouseenter', function () {
     $(this).effect("shake", { times:2, distance: 3}, 120);
});
```

And it works but on IE and Firefox the image keeps shaking all the time even if the mouse is right in the middle of the image. it seems that moving image trigers mouseenter event all the time??
Cannot fix this, strange issue. On chrome it trigers just once.

Comment: seems fine to me http://plnkr.co/edit/RdvgftaR24CD55dU6Qux?p=preview

Comment: in my Firefox (newest) it keeps shaking all the time, and in IE 9 also: http://plnkr.co/edit/QoHATbeq2mm22N4YexBz?p=preview

Comment: I was checking using chrome

Comment: Looks like the mouseenter function is keep firing

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a real solution to your problem but you could easily avoid it by checking if a variable has a certain value and reset it if the user leaves the area.

```
var active = false;
$('#perlabot').on('mouseenter', function () {
    if (active === false) {
        active = true;
        $(this).effect("shake", {
            times: 2,
            distance: 3
        }, 120);
    }
}).mouseleave(function () {
    active = false;
});
```

Might not be the smartest way to solve it but it works fine in every browser I tested it (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, IE 10 and 9)

<kbd>[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/BqQNJ/2/)</kbd>

Comment: I guess the issue is that the element gets moved around, so it counts as a new `mouseenter` event. If you use e.g. `.effect('highlight');` it just triggers the effect once.

Answer (score 1):

Try this option. Similar concept to the above answer, but I think more robust. (no global status variable for example)

```
function shakeIt(obj)
{
    obj.mouseleave(function () {
        obj.on("mouseenter", function () { shakeIt(obj); });
        obj.off("mouseleave");
    });
    obj.off("mouseenter");
    obj.effect("shake", { distance: "3", times: "2" }, 120);
}
$("#perlabot").on("mouseenter", function () { shakeIt($(this)); });
```